# Is it still supported to interactively change to vi mode in IPython via %config magic?

Tags: ipython, key-bindings

For me when I try to interactively switch to vi mode in a quite recent version of IPython, it simply stops reacting to all keyboard input except for Ctrl+D.

```
$ python3 -m IPython
Python 3.6.9 (default, Jan 26 2021, 15:33:00) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.16.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: %config TerminalInteractiveShell.editing_mode
Out[1]: 'emacs'

In [2]: %config TerminalInteractiveShell.editing_mode='vi'
```

Specifying on the command line works perfectly fine however, so I don't think it's my terminal or anything like that

```
python3 -m IPython --TerminalInteractiveShell.editing_mode=vi
```

But I am testing this in:

- Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
- GNOME Terminal 3.28.2

Answer (score 0):

It should, if it does not it's likely a bug, the vi mode does not have  a lot of users; and even less that dynamically switch.

It's likely a question of propagating changes to TerminalInteractiveShell.editing_mode to other places in the codebase.

Feel free to open a bug, and we'll do our best to guide you on how to fix it.

Comment: Update: I reported an issue and it has been fixed here

https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/13091